# why jenkins showing git, maven not found error even git and maven installed?

Tags: git, jenkins, tomcat, devops, integration

`hi there,hope you are doing well.
I am new to Jenkins, and errors are encountered during practice. i took a sample project. error and jenkins file content posted below please have a look into it. feel free to ask if you have any questions. please suggest solution.

Thank you for your support and help.`

```
Error as below

Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkins-decnew from git https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
**Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
**The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential gitid
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline1/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.40.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkins-decnew"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Git Checkout)
[Pipeline] git
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential gitid
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline1/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.40.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -b master c8f4db412eaf023b2ae78c1a9e168db17ea6ac73 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkins-decnew"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Maven Build)
[Pipeline] sh
**+ mvn clean package
**/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline1@tmp/durable-7e042d4d/script.sh: line 1: **mvn: command not found**
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (deploy-dev)
Stage "deploy-dev" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
REST API
Jenkins 2.401.1
```

`jenkins file content from here :)`

```
pipeline{

    agent any
    
    environment{
        PATH = "/opt/maven3/bin:$PATH"
    }
    stages{
        stage("Git Checkout"){
            steps{
                git credentialsId: 'gitid', url: 'https://github.com/kdhani/myweb-p1.git'
            }
        }
        stage("Maven Build"){
            steps{
                sh "mvn clean package"
                sh "mv target/*.war target/myweb.war"
            }
        }
        stage("deploy-dev"){
            steps{
                sshagent(['tomcat-new']) {
                    
                sh """
                    scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/myweb.war  ec2-user@172.31.33.108:/home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/webapps/
                    
                    ssh ec2-user@172.31.33.108 /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/bin/shutdown.sh
                    
                    ssh ec2-user@172.31.33.108 /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/bin/startup.sh
                
                """
            }
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `git` is found on the agent path, or Jenkins would not have been able to clone/restore (checkout) your repository.

Second, then error is only for Maven:

```
**/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline1@tmp/durable-7e042d4d/script.sh: 
line 1: **mvn: command not found**
```

If you have the [Pipeline Maven Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/#plugin-content-installation), check your Jenkins "Global Tools Configuration" setting page:

[image: https://www.edureka.co/community/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=6487223072891694295]

Make sure you have a Maven declared with a path valid for the agent you are running it on.

Check "[Configuring Java and Maven in Jenkins](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking-and-servers/9781786465702/2/ch02lvl1sec16/configuring-java-and-maven-in-jenkins)" for illustrations.

You can also add [maven parameters to your job](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/#plugin-content-usage):

```yaml
node {
  stage ('Build') {

    git url: 'https://github.com/cyrille-leclerc/multi-module-maven-project'

    withMaven(
        // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
        maven: 'maven-3', // (1)
        // Use `$WORKSPACE/.repository` for local repository folder to avoid shared repositories
        mavenLocalRepo: '.repository', // (2)
        // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
        // We recommend to define Maven settings.xml globally at the folder level using
        // navigating to the folder configuration in the section "Pipeline Maven Configuration / Override global Maven configuration"
        // or globally to the entire master navigating to  "Manage Jenkins / Global Tools Configuration"
        mavenSettingsConfig: 'my-maven-settings' // (3)
    ) {

      // Run the maven build
      sh "mvn clean verify"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe & FindBugs & SpotBugs reports...
  }
}
```

Comment: `node ("windows")` good joke ;)

Comment: @igops Good point, not sure why I put `"windows"` there. I have edited the answer to remove it.